# Nginx redirect by client IP

Tags: redirect, nginx, ip

I want to redirect client to special page if his IP contain in my special database.

My database in ip_addresses.csv like:
191.11.23.3
3.4.11.22
5.117.33.4

How can I do it by nginx.conf?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should merge your database into `nginx.conf` (I've no idea how can use CSV in nginx easily).

You can use [geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html). First, untested example:

```
geo $redirectip {
  default 0;
  # you can use "include" of course, see examples in documentation
  192.11.23.3 1;
  3.4.11.22 1;
  5.117.33.4 1;
  ...
}

server {
  if ($redirectip) {
    return/rewrite/whatever_you_want...;
  }
}
```